# Different color of texts in the same textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using following code

```
 Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.signup_text));
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, 18, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    signupText.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

However my textView is showing the same color as set in its xml i-e skin color.

I want to show substring from 0 - 18 as BLACK and rest color as skin color. What is wrong here?

Comment: code is working very fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno whether you are trying to use two colors in the same string if so,You could try some thing like this

In your strings.xml

```
  <string name="hello"><![CDATA[ TEXT IN BLACK <b><font color=#ff0000>TEXT IN RED</b>]]></string>
```

in your activity

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.hello)));
```

Then `TEXT IN BLACK` will be seen in normal color and `TEXT IN RED` will be shown in red color

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Resources res = getResources();

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(res.getString(R.string.signup_text));
```